# How can I get mysql variables and show as if statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show available appointment times by matching a list against those times that have already been picked and stored in a database.

I can not get the `if($v== $info_check['appt_time']){continue;}` for each `$info_check['appt_time']` stored in the database.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or a better way to go about this.

```
    <?
$start = strtotime('09:00am');//one hour less my stores start time
$end = strtotime('8:00pm');//my stores stop time
$range = array();
while ($start !== $end)
{
    $start = strtotime('+60 minutes',$start);
    $range[] = date('h:ia', $start);
}
?>
<select name='appt_time'>
<?
foreach ($range as $key=> $v) {

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("my_appointments");

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments");

if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0){
while ($info_check = mysql_fetch_array( $check )){

    if($v== $info_check['appt_time']){
        continue;   

    }

}}
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You should really look into PDO as a way to handle databases in PHP.

Comment: What format is the `appt_time` in your database? varchar? TIMESTAMP? DATETIME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to connect to the database again and again. You also do not need to send the select querys again and again. Furthermore it is much easier for other people to read your code if you don't use < ? ? > all the time and work more with proper formatting.

Here is one example how your code could look like. I didn't test it, but it should be way more efficient and should work the way you want.

```
<?php
#You should put this in something like config.inc.php and include the file here
#Don't(!) put the mysql_connect in a loop. That will decrease performance.
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("my_appointments");

#I expect your database doesn't change during the foreach loop, so there is no need to read the db more than once
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments");
$dbEntryCount = mysql_num_rows($check);
for ($i=0; $i < $dbEntryCount; $i++)
{
    $info_check = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
    $database_range[]=$info_check['appt_time'];
}

$start = strtotime('09:00am');//one hour less my stores start time
$end = strtotime('8:00pm');//my stores stop time
$range = array();
while ($start !== $end)
{
    $start = strtotime('+60 minutes',$start);
    $range[] = date('h:ia', $start);
}

echo '
    <select name="appt_time">
        <option value=""> - - - Choose - - - </option>
';

foreach ($range as $key=> $v) 
{
    #http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
    if (in_array($v, $database_range))
    {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$v.'">'.$v.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

?>

EDIT:
Someone asked about the type of variable you are using for appt_time. You can use var_dump($database_range); var_dump($range); at the end of your code (before the ? >) to check if both arrays use the same format.

EDIT:
Thanks... I edited

```
{
    $info_check = mysql_fetch_array( $check )
    $database_range[i]=$info_check['appt_time']
}
```

to

```
{
    $info_check = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
    $database_range[]=$info_check['appt_time'];
}
```

and it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use $v after your for loop which will be out of scope.

```
<select name='appt_time'>
<?
foreach ($range as $key=> $v) {

  mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
  mysql_select_db("my_appointments");

  $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointments");

  if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0){
    while ($info_check = mysql_fetch_array( $check )){

      if($v== $info_check['appt_time']){
         continue;   

      }

   }  
} //<-- variable $v scope ends here
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></option> //<-- Move this line into while loop and try
<? } ?>
</select>
```

new while loop will look like

```
      while ($info_check = mysql_fetch_array( $check )){

          if($v== $info_check['appt_time']){
             continue;   

          }

          echo "<option value=". $v .">".$v."</option>";
       }
```

Comment: thanks.  I tried that, but still not working... just shows all hours

Comment: Did you verify if both time variables(from database & the php one) are in same format?